# Listbox ObserverableCollection Binding is not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I want to show my `ObserverableCollection` in my `ListBox` per binding in the xaml, but when i start it only shows `projectname.classname`. Thanks for any help.

**Question:** Why do my Listbox show `projectname.Class2` and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Property ListWhatever As New ObservableCollection(Of Class2)
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
        Initialize()
    End Sub
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Sub Initialize()
        ListWhatever.Add(New Klasse2("test"))
        ListWhatever.Add(New Klasse2("hallo"))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public Property wort
    Public Sub New(wort As String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListWhatever}"/>
```

Comment: As a note, there is currently no reason why MainWindow should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. It's pointless. Also, `Public Property wort` should certainly be `Public Property wort As String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a DataTemplate with an element that binds to Class2's properties:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListWhatever}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding wort}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) for details.

---

You also have to assign the `wort` property:

```
Public Class Class2
    Public Property wort As String

    Public Sub New(wort As String)
        Me.wort = wort
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: now theres no text. **BUT** there are two clickable items in the `ListBox`

Comment: In the Class2 constructor you did not assign the value of the `wort` parameter to the `wort` property.